# Independant massage therapist with dangerous stress level. Told to take time off but unsure how

Tags: professionalism, stress

I am an independent massage therapist, single mother of 3 and having health issues due to stress. Being that Im an independent contractor, I don't have paid sick leave. Lately, Ive been experiencing tightness in my chest, sometimes pain/discomfort in neck and upper back while at work or en route to work. The cardiologist says to avoid stress at all costs until I can have further testing of my heart done. I dont see how this is possible being that if I dont work, I cant take care of my children's needs. Is there any state (I live in CA) assistance that I can apply for so I can transition on a less stressful level. I know the cause of my health concerns is where I work and know I need to change locations. Fear of the unknown (how will I survive)is what is stopping me. I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: You are in a tough spot and I feel for you.  But this is not really a question we can help with here at SE.  We are a Q&A Site that deals with navigating the workplace.  We could probably help you with addressing your stress from work, or requesting the time off, but this is not the type of problem we can help with.  Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about CA but generally this is something that could be covered under short term disability insurance.  If you are an independent contractor then it is unlikely your workplace provides that for you unless you got it on your own.

With that being said the only other option I see would be applying for Social Security Disability benefits, however, the caveat there is that this does not cover temporary or short term conditions or disabilities.  You would need to apply and convince doctors and the Social Security office that your condition is a permanent one that greatly affects your ability to hold a stable job that allows you to provide for yourself and your children.  This is would be difficult to get approved for generalized anxiety and stress disorders without legal consultation and help.

If you feel you need to take a leave of absence from your profession and are worried about providing for your kids then there are public assistance programs in California geared towards helping those in your situation.  You could be eligible for food stamps and free medical care for your children based on your income level, however outright welfare may be harder to get.  California and other states under intense lobbying and political pressure are reformulating their welfare programs to be geared towards influencing recipients to eventually find work.  Being as you are currently working and Social Security wouldn't easily view your situation as a long term disability you may be in for a hard time.

As someone who suffers from generalized anxiety disorder I sympathize with you deeply.  The world is not kind to our suffering.  I suggest seeking the help of a psychiatrist or psychologist as there are medicines that can help greatly in the short term though I wouldn't recommend building a habit.  Beyond that try doing things to lower your stress level.  I find working out, meditating, yoga/pilates/stretching, drinking lots of water, getting more sleep, cutting out caffeine and alcohol, *getting a nice massage* :) and sometimes just taking an hour in your busy day to read a book will help.

Furthermore unless you are truly living hand to mouth, sometimes cutting your hours is a good compromise to outright quitting your job.